# Generic django admin per client

Tags: django, django-admin

In my django project, i would like to use Django Admin for multiple organization. So in django urls system, i try to use a system like that :

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('<organization>/admin', admin.site.urls)
]
```

With that syntax,on a simple example (default startproject+setup), i got an 'NoReverseMatch' :

```
Reverse for 'logout' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<client>[^/]+)\\/admin\\/logout\\/$']
```

At the end i try to implement a system like that:

- Basic auth user (maybe change backend for email)
- Organization:

  - Organization_User (inherit from basic auth or relationship)
  - Organization_Area (manyTomany with Organization_User)

and for urls i don't know if syntax bellow works:

- www.example.com/admin  => admin SuperUser only
- www.example.com/organization1/admin => Admin for Organization 1
- www.example.com/organization2/admin => Admin for Organization 2

I'm asking myself, is it possible to do that only with Django Admin system ?
For example, use one Admin and try URL filtering or use AdminSite inheritence

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you just assign users to groups depending on which organisation they belong to? Then alter the groups permissions so they can only see the parts you wish them to have access to.

Comment: I don't want to use a permission group per organization.I just use group to assign level of permissions for user in organization (example: Admin, Regular). For my usecase, i use group permission only for displaying or not, table in django admin cause my organization's clients have several user restriction  (Admin, Regular). So, i use url (subdomain or argument) to detect organization with middleware, Then i use get_queryset method+ModelAdmin method's overide to filter user and records they can see. But i'm not sure if it's correct to do this like that

Comment: In general, the Django admin pages should only be used for staff members. It's not really built to be used by 'normal users'. If you are already customizing the request URLs, applying permission groups and modifying query sets, you would be better off just building your own post-login pages for the site.

Comment: Two Scoops of Django is an excellent resource for Django best practices and I highly recommend it fr any time you start working with something new in Django. They state in section 19.2 'It’s usually not worth it to heavily customize the Django admin. Sometimes, creating a simple view
or form from scratch results in the same desired functionality with a lot less work.'